# Does malloc() offer benefits compared to global arrays for fixed array sizes?

Tags: c, memory-management, static, malloc, heap-memory

I'm currently writing a socket program that requires a 100MB buffer size for sending data. This buffer size will ALWAYS be a fixed size and lasts the entire duration of the program.

Are there any benefits of using malloc() versus just declaring a global array?

Note: the only benefit I can think of is that malloc() will tell you if the memory allocation fails as opposed to global arrays which might just cause undefined behavior when you request too much memory.

Comment: As far as I know a global array will not have undefined behavior. The program will fail to start. Or, if running in Linux with memory overcommit enabled it may be killed with an OOM unexpectedly. But that isn't undefined either.

Comment: If a static array is too large, the compiler tells me, and there will be no executable.

Comment: It's implementation-dependent, but I don't think any good implementation will let you compile with a static buffer too large.

Comment: Depends what "too large" means; you can certainly compile a program with an array that fits within the address space provided by the architecture, but which won't run on your system due to not actually having that much memory.

Comment: I would go with dynamic allocation, because it will guarantee compilation of the program and will fail only on systems with specific limitations, but will work on the others.

Comment: @Barmar It appears I'm working with a "not good implementation" which is making me opt for the malloc route.

Comment: @Izzo I don't think your implementation is "not good". You probably have some other issue, and this is an XY-problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I assure you this implementation is not good. The compiler doesn't report errors half the time and indicates success.

Comment: @Izzo But why do you think there is a problem then? And what happens the other half of the time.

Comment: Using a global array has a few advantages: Less error checking. If the array is non-mutable and initialized during compilation, it is easy to share between different processes. And if the array is only used by a library, you don't need library initialization functions that are a pain in multithreaded programs. That said, I don't understand why you need 100MB send-buffer.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any benefits of using malloc() versus just declaring a global array?

With a  global array, the entire 100MB  array is initialized, default to 0, at program start-up - that can take time.

With `malloc()`, not such initialization required.

Conceivable, that means the `malloc()` approach starts faster.

This difference may be an advantage.

Comment: On a typical system, 0-intialization on startup of global data is zero-cost. (Or at least cheaper than a `malloc` call)

Comment: @HAL9000 Agree about zero cost in program space, but not certainly 0 cost in execution time.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica All space allocated to your program is 0-initialized for security. With malloc, you have to 0-initialize it again because you aren't sure.

Comment: @user253751 "With malloc, you have to 0-initialize it again because you aren't sure." No, OP's use of the buffer imposed no zeroing requirement.  OP's code could move right into writing the allocated buffer without a prior zeroing.  C also does not imposes _security_ requirement per "All space allocated to your program is 0-initialized for security."  Global variables lacking explicit initialization are zero'd by spec.  This happens before `main()` is called and takes time.

Comment: @chux, Assuming you have a mmu and a sane OS, all global data on startup may be mapped to a single zero-valued page with "fork-on-write". This is basically a single `mmap` call. When you call `malloc` (assuming you need more virtual memory), `malloc` will also do a `mmap` which, because of security, will do the same zero valued page with "fork-on-write" trick. Just that you have more record keeping overhead. On embedded systems, things are even simpler. Memory is zero on power-on. Naturally there *are* exceptions, like MS-DOS.

Comment: Just as a test, I made an executable with 10GB global array, and got "Segmentation Error" on startup. Reduced the size to 1GB, and it ran and finished "Instantaneously". I see the question of startup runtime cost from large global arrays as settled.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Any sane *operating system* imposes the security requirement that all memory is 0-initialized (or otherwise initialized) before your program has access to it. C does not exist in a vacuum.

Comment: @user253751 OP is asking about potential differences. global memory is C specified to be zero'd.  Allocated memory is not so required. Thus a C compliant program can skip the zeroing time via `malloc()`.  C does not even require an OS.  100s of millions of embedded machines each year lack one.  HAL9000, embedded initial zeroing of memory that does not require zeroing is can often be disabled to improve  performance.